# Searching Multiple Rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hello everyone I have ran into a small problem i need to know how to be able to search multiple rows in my database and i am having some difficulty with my code can you please take a look at my query

```
$raw_results =  DB::table('students')->select('Name', 'Date' ,'Class')->where('Name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->get();
```

Comment: i tried tacing on more table names but it gave me a error

Comment: Have you tried using the `mysqli` object?

Comment: no i have to use a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `orWhere()` as part of your query to add additional constraints.

```
$rawResults = DB::table('students')
    ->select('Name', 'Date', 'Class')
    ->where('Name', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->orWhere('Class', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
    ->get();
```